# Are arrays in Ruby and similarly typed languages vectors?

Tags: ruby, arrays, r, math, vector

R wraps csv'd lists of numbers (comma separated values i.e. `1, 2, 3`) in the `c()` function, a part of the R core library, which converts csv'd lists of numbers into vectors.

These vectors look like Ruby or Java arrays, with the exception that these csv'd lists are wrapped in `c()` rather than `[]`. It seems like arrays are really a subset of vectors. Is it true? And if so, what does this mean when it comes to arrays and matrices?

One discussion on the subject I found stated that arrays are static vectors. But in Ruby, arrays aren't static. In Ruby, arrays are vectors?

Comment: In instances I've seen, Vector is a subset of Array (a 1-D Array), not the other way around.

Comment: This question seems unclear to me. Are you asking why R doesn't call these arrays, or why other languages don't call these vectors? Note that each language has its own implementation details that don't always match up to how other languages name their types. (In Python, the default container is called a `list`, but is actually implemented with a (resizable) array).

Comment: Vectors are defined in physics as "things" with a direction and a magnitude. Now I haven't gone deep into physics (I was a chemistry guy), but that definition, which is my only present definition of vectors, does not seem to apply here. If there is any confusion on your part about the question its due to the fact that I'm somewhat perplexed as well.

Comment: Based off my cursory studies just now, 'vector' and 'one-dimensional-array' seem to point to each other. but a multi-dimensional array is what, a matrix? So there seems, at least at first, to be some parallelism here. The primary difference would be the static versus dynamic components, which in ruby, is a moot point. In ruby, and other interpreted as opposed to compiled languages, the line between array and vector blurs a great deal it seems

Comment: It sounds like you're used to the concepts of "vector" and "array" (or matrix) in the context of mathematical objects. It's important to remember that from a computer's perspective, the concept of "extra dimensions" makes little sense when it comes time to store the values in memory. So most languages will internally store higher dimensional arrays as a single list of values, and simply track the rows/columns with some extra bookkeeping information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, in R an array is just a vector equipped with attributes that give the dimensions of the array.

From `?array`:

> Details:
>
> An array in R can have one, two or more dimensions.  It is simply
>      a vector which is stored with additional attributes giving the
>      dimensions (attribute ‘"dim"’) and optionally names for those
>      dimensions (attribute ‘"dimnames"’).
>
> A two-dimensional array is the same thing as a ‘matrix’.
>
> One-dimensional arrays often look like vectors, but may be handled
>      differently by some functions: ‘str’ does distinguish them in
>      recent versions of R.
>
> The ‘"dim"’ attribute is an integer vector of length one or more
>      containing non-negative values: the product of the values must
>      match the length of the array.

Maybe the easiest way to see this for yourself is to have a look at a vector, a matrix, and a higher dimensional array, like this:

```
a <- array(1:12, dim=c(2,2,3))
m <- matrix(1:4, ncol=2)
v <- c(1,2)

is(a)
# [1] "array"     "matrix"    "structure" "vector"    "vector"  
is(m)
# [1] "matrix"    "array"     "structure" "vector"
is(v)
# [1] "numeric" "vector" 

attributes(a)
# $dim
# [1] 2 2 3
attributes(m)
# $dim
# [1] 2 2
attributes(v)
# NULL

## Finally, try this
v <- 1:12
dim(v) <- c(2,2,3)
v
```